# Difference between Run-Time Polymorphism and Compile-Time Polymorphism in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, run-time-polymorphism

I wanted to ask how what is exactly Run Time polymorphism, why does it is called Run Time Polymorphism, I was asked this question in an Interview ?

I searched and found the phrase "The function call is resolved at run time." but what does this mean.

Comment: If you were to open your C++ textbook to chapter 1 and start reading it, at some point all of these concepts will be explained, in due time. C++ is just too complicated and cannot be effectively learned by random keyword searches, and asking for an explanation of each randomly-selected topic. An organized, textbook-guided curriculum is necessary, with each concept logically introduced, starting with the basics, and incrementally moving ahead to each progressively complicated topic, in each chapter. Then, when your textbook gets to this part, it should be very easy to understand it. Good luck.